# Как в OpenGL (core-profile) отрисовать разные меши?

Tags: c++, opengl, шейдеры

Для отрисовки разных мешей нужно для каждого меша создать свои шейдеры и свою шейдерную программу? Если это так, то какую шейдерную программу передавать для матрицы камеры и проекции?

(Разные меши - меши у которых разный размер, цвет и тд.)

Передача матриц камеры и проекции в вершинный шейдер:

```
viewUniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(m_shaderProgram, "view");
glUniformMatrix4fv(viewUniformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));

projUniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation(m_shaderProgram, "projection");
glUniformMatrix4fv(projUniformLocation, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
```

вершинный шейдер:

```
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;

uniform mat4 transform;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * transform * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: Если формат вершин у них одинаковый, то для каждого меша достаточно будет создать свой вершинный буфер, или даже запихать все в один и потом отрисовывать все вместе или отдельно.

Comment: так а что делать с шейдерной программой?

Comment: Ничего не делать.

Comment: хорошо, возможно я туплю, поэтому на ссылку на репозиторий. Посмотри и скажи что не так(если не сложно конечно, заранее спасибо) https://github.com/artemko22/Hyko_Engine.git
 Самые основные файлы:
1. Triangle.cpp/.h
2. UpdateEvents.cpp/.h
3. Shader.cpp/.h

Comment: Вы понимаете, что uniform-ы у шейдера можно менять?

Answer (score 1):

Вот вам примерный код, как организовать базовый Render(**Код примерные, есть какие моменты оптимизировать и отрефакторить**). Как вы можете обратить внимание, 1 шейдер используется, а модели могут разные, главное что бы корректно соотносились индексы вершин и их позиции, нормали ( в примерно), текстурные координаты.

Какие проблемы есть у данного решения:

1. glDraw операции - тяжелые и если у вас будет много объектов на отрисовку 1000 и более у вас будет fps крайне низкий.
2. Для другого типа моделей, если нужны дополнительные вещи (свет, фильтры и т.д) понадобятся другие шейдеры и с ними надо уметь работать.

Для первого пункта - решение использовать большой buffer, заполнять его и потом через GLBufferSubData добавлять, почитайте / посмотрите про [Batch Rendering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Th4huqR77rI&list=PLlrATfBNZ98f5vZ8nJ6UengEkZUMC4fy5&ab_channel=TheCherno) или  попробуйте использовать [Instancing Rendering](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Instancing).

```
class Shader
{
public:
    unsigned int ID;
    // constructor generates the shader on the fly
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Shader(std::string vertexCode, std::string fragmentCode)
    {
        const char* vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
        const char * fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();
        // 2. compile shaders
        unsigned int vertex, fragment;
        // vertex shader
        vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &vShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vertex);
        checkCompileErrors(vertex, "VERTEX");
        // fragment Shader
        fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fragment, 1, &fShaderCode, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fragment);
        checkCompileErrors(fragment, "FRAGMENT");
 
        // shader Program
        ID = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(ID, vertex);
        glAttachShader(ID, fragment);
 
        glLinkProgram(ID);
        checkCompileErrors(ID, "PROGRAM");
        // delete the shaders as they're linked into our program now and no longer necessery
        glDeleteShader(vertex);
        glDeleteShader(fragment);
    }
 
    void use()
    {
        glUseProgram(ID);
    }

    void unUse()
    {
        glUseProgram(0);
    }
   
    void setBool(const std::string &name, bool value) const
    {
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), (int)value);
    }
 
    void setInt(const std::string &name, int value) const
    {
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), value);
    }
 
    void setFloat(const std::string &name, float value) const
    {
        glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), value);
    }
 
    void setMatrix(const std::string &name, const float* matrix) const {
        glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()),
                           1, GL_FALSE, matrix);
    }
private:
 
    void checkCompileErrors(GLuint shader, std::string type)
    {
        GLint success;
        GLchar infoLog[1024];
        if(type != "PROGRAM")
        {
            glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
            if(!success)
            {
                glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
                std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER_COMPILATION_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog << "\n -- --------------------------------------------------- -- " << std::endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
            if(!success)
            {
                glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
                std::cout << "ERROR::PROGRAM_LINKING_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog << "\n -- --------------------------------------------------- -- " << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
};

struct Vertex {
  glm::vec3 position;
  glm::vec3 normal;
  glm::vec2 textureCoord;
};

class Model {
public:
   bool loadFromFile(std::string path); //

   std::vector<Texture> getTextures() const { return m_textures; }
   unsinged int getVAO() const { return VAO;}
private: 
   void setupGL();
private:
   std::vector<Vertex> m_vertices;
   std::vector<unsingned int> m_indices;
   std::vector<Texture> m_textures; 
  
   unsigned int VAO;
};

bool Model::loadFromFile(std::string path) {
     /// загружаем модель, возьмем для примера .obj формат
    
    setupGL(); /// для примера сделаем здесь, после того, как наши массивы заполнены
    return true;
}

void Model::setupGL() {
    unsigned int VBO, EBO;
    
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(Vertex), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(unsigned int), &indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)0);
    // vertex normals
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, normal));
    // vertex texture coords
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vertex), (void*)offsetof(Vertex, textureCoord));
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

class RenderObject {
public:
   void setModel(Model& model) {
     m_model = model; 
   }
 
   void setPosition(glm::vec3 position) {
      m_position = position;
   }
   
   void setScale(glm::vec3 scale) {
      m_scale = scale;
   }

   void setRotation(glm::vec3 rotation) {
      m_rotation = rotation;
   }

   glm::mat4 getModelMatrix() { 
      return glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.f), m_position) * glm::toMat4(glm::quat(m_rotation) * glm::scake(glm::mat4(1.f), m_scale);
   }

   const Model& getModel() const { return m_model; }
private:
   glm::vec3 m_position, m_rotation, m_scale;
   Model m_model;
};

class OpenGLRender {
public:
    // ... //
    void setup(glm::vec2 windowSize, Camera& camera);
    void render(std::vector<RenderObject>& objects);
private:
   Shader m_modelShader;
   glm::mat4 m_projection;
   Camera& m_camera;
};

const char* vertexModelShader = R("
 #version 330 core
 
 layout(location = 0) vec3 inPos;
 layout(location = 1) vec2 inTextureCoord;  
 
 out vec2 outTextureCoord;

 uniform mat4 model;
 uniform mat4 projection;
 uniform mat4 view;

 void main()
 {
    outTextureCoord = inTextureCoord;
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);
 }
");

const char* fragmentModelShader = R("
 #version 330 core
 
 out vec4 fragColor;
 in vec2 outTextureCoord;
 uniform sampler2D textureSampler;
 
 void main()
 {
    fragColor = texture(textureSampler, outTextureCoord);    
 }
");

OpenGLRender::setup() {
   glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   /// есть смысл обновлять если FOV = камера zoom обычно или WindowSize изменился
   m_projection = glm::persperctive(FOV, windowSize.x / windowSize.y, zNear, zFar);
   
   m_shader.create(vertexModelShader, fragmentFragmentShader);
   m_modelShader.use();
   m_modelShader.setMatrix("projection", glm::value_ptr(m_projection));
   m_modelShader.unUse();
}

OpenGLRender::render(std::vector<RenderObject>& objects) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(0.49f, 0.89f, 0.98f, 1.f);

   m_modelShader.use();
    
   m_modelShader.setMatrix("projection", glm::value_ptr(m_projection));
   m_modelShader.setMatrix("view", glm::value_ptr(m_camera.getViewMatrix()));

   for(auto& it: objects) {
      m_shader.setMatrix("model", glm::value_ptr(it.getModelMatrix()));
      auto& model = it.getModel();
      auto& textures = model.getTextures();
      for(std::size_t i = 0; i < textures.count(); ++i) {
          glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE2D, textures[i].getID());
          glActivateTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + i);
          m_shader.setInt("textureSample" + std::to_string(i), i); // фрагметному шейдеру надо дать конкретное значение sampler2D;
      }
      glBindVertexArray(model.getVAO());
      glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,  model.getIndicesCount(),GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
       /// сбрасываем значения для следующих моделей иначе можно получить некорректное отображение
       glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE2D, 0);
       glActivateTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
       glBindVertexArray(0);
   }

   m_modelShader.unUse(); 
}


class Application {
public:
    /// ctor / dtor ///
    void run();
private:
    void setup();
    void handleOSEvents();
    void update(float deltaTime);
    void render();
private:
    Window m_window;
    OpenGLRender m_render;
    Model model;
    Model model1;
    std::vector<RenderObject> m_objects;
};

void Application::setup() {
    m_render.setup(m_window.getSize());
    
    model.loadFromFile("model.obj");
    model1.loadFromFile("model1.obj");
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
      RenderObject gameObject;
      gameObject.setModel(model);
      gameObject.setPosition({ 10 * i, 0, 10});
      gameObject.setScale({1, 1, 1});

      m_objects.emplace_back(gameObject);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
      RenderObject gameObject;
      gameObject.setModel(model1);
      gameObject.setPosition({ 20 * i, 0, 10});
      gameObject.setScale({2, 2, 2});

      m_objects.emplace_back(gameObject);
    }
}

void Application::run() {
    setup();
    
    Clock clock;
    constexpr int maxFrames = 60;
    constexpr float frameTime = 1.F / static_cast<float>(maxFrames);
    float processedTime = 0.F;
    
    while(window.isOpen) {
        float elapsedTime = clock.getElapsedTime();
        processedTime += elapsedTime;
        while(processedTime >= frameTime) {
            handleOSEvents();
            update(frameTime);
        }
        render();
    }
}

void Application::handleOSEvents() {
    OSEvent event{};
    while(m_window.pollEvents(event)) {
        if(event.type == OSEvent::KeyPressed && event.key.code == OS::Keyboard::Esc)
            window.close();
        /// Keyboard / Mouse events
    }
}

void Application::update(float deltaTime) {
    /// update GameObjects using deltaTime ///
    for(auto& it:m_objects)
        it.update(deltaTime);
}

Application::render() {
    m_window.clear(Colors::Blue);
    
    m_render.render(m_objects);
    
    m_window.swapBuffers() // переставляем передний / задний buffer
}


int main() {
    Application app{vec2u{1024, 512}, "MyGame"};
    
    try {
        app.run();
    }
    catch(const std::exception& exception) {
        std::cerr << "Exception thrown:" << exception.what() << "\n";
        return -1;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```